# React Router does not match any other routes except '/'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is the code :

```
import React,{propTypes} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route, Link,Switch  } from 'react- 
router-dom'
import {ReportList} from './reportList'
import {NewReportForm} from './newReportForm'


export function App(){
var instance = Object.create(React.Component.prototype)


instance.render = function(){
    return (  <Router >                  
              <Switch>
              <Route  path="/get"  component={ReportList}  />
              <Route  path="/add"  component={NewReportForm}  />
              </Switch>
              </Router>
           )
}
return instance
```

}

The router does not match any /get or /add and the component does not load. But when I do this ->

```
 <Router >                  
              <Switch>
              <Route  path="/"  component={ReportList}  />
              <Route  path="/add"  component={NewReportForm}  />
              </Switch>
              </Router>
```

then the component loads for *ReportList*. What is happening , What am i doing wrong? How can i get it to working for both the route /get and /add. I want separate components to load for each route.

package.json ->

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "xlsx-populate": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
```

Webpack ->

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var parentDir = path.join(__dirname, './');

module.exports = {
    node: {
        console: false,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    entry: [
        path.join(parentDir, 'index.js')
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },{
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loder", "less-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: parentDir + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route  path="/"  component={ReportList}  />
<Route  path="/add"  component={NewReportForm}  />
```

In react router, this needs to be

```
<Route exact path="/"  component={ReportList}  />
<Route path="/add"  component={NewReportForm}  />
```

Because right now the path /anything will match with "/", therefore rendering what's in your first route.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but when I do this nothing gets rendered...no message on console...nothing whatsoever